# How to setup a multi-module gradle project with Quarkus?

Tags: gradle, quarkus

A multi-module gradle project with the Quarkus plugin applied in the root `build.gradle.kts` fails at the `:quarkusBuild` step with a `NoSuchElementException`:

```
> Task :quarkusBuild FAILED
building quarkus jar

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':quarkusBuild'.
> java.util.NoSuchElementException
```

The root `build.gradle.kts` is like so:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.72"
    id("io.quarkus") version "1.9.1.Final"
}

group = "org.example"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

subprojects {
    
    apply {
        plugin("kotlin")
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation(kotlin("stdlib"))
    }
}
```

However move the line `id("io.quarkus") version "1.9.1.Final"` to the sub projects'  `build.gradle.kts` and the build succeeds. It seems that the quarkus build step is run where the plugin is declared, rather than where it is actually applied.

Ideally I want to declare the plugin once in the root, then apply it to subprojects only, not have it execute against the root project, where there's obviously nothing to build.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `apply false`

```
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.72" apply false
    id("io.quarkus") version "1.9.1.Final" apply false
}
```

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:subprojects_plugins_dsl

Your build also assumes that every sub-module will be a Kotlin module which may or may not be true. You can do something a little more like this to apply specific configurations to specific tasks:

```
subprojects { subproject ->
    subproject.tasks.withType(JavaCompile).configureEach {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
    subproject.tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).configureEach {
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        }
    }
}
```